# IQueryable Not Returning Associated Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF6, I have a 1:N relationship between Owners and Widgets.  I can't seem to get the associated Owner information.

```
public partial class Owners
{
    public Owners()
    {
        Widgets = new HashSet<Widgets>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Widgets> Widgets { get; set; }
}

public partial class Widgets
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string WidgetName { get; set; }
    public string WidgetType { get; set; }
    public virtual Owners Owners { get; set; }
}

public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1(): base("name=Model1"){}
    public virtual DbSet<Owners> Owners { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Widgets> Widgets { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Owners>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Widgets)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Owners)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.OwnerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run  following query I only get information for Widgets
and nothing for Owners.  If I pull the generated SQL out and run it in the database I get all the Information and Associated Entity Information?
I believe I'm overlooking something simple here.

```
using (var db = new Model1())
{
    var rslt = db.Widgets.Include(y => y.Owners);
    var rslt2 = await rslt.Where(s => s.WidgetType == "Garthug").ToListAsync();
    return rslt2;
}
```

This is the EF generated SQL statement that gets created and shows all the correct information that I'm looking for when I run in the Database. (I hand typed it but it should be correct)

```
SELECT 
Widgets.id AS id, 
Widgets.OwnerId AS OwnerId, 
Widgets.WidgetName AS WidgetName, 
Widgets.WidgetsType AS WidgetType, 
Owners.Id AS Id1, 
Owners.OwnerName AS OwnerName
FROM  [dbo].Widgets AS Widgets
INNER JOIN [dbo].Owners AS Owner ON Widgets.OwnerId = Owners.Id
WHERE Widgets.WidgetType = 'Garthug'
```

It Appears that my setup is Correct for EVERY table except Asp Identity Tables... Does anyone know why?

Comment: So if you look at `Widget.Owner` is `null`?

Comment: That is correct.  I can see it in the Query, I've even tried Changing the Order of the .Include() to see if the Query Shape is losing the associated data. No luck.

Comment: I'd try to add `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` before your overriden `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: Owner have Id as a string while Widget have id as an int.

Comment: @jdweng What difference would that make? I have entities with `Guid` as Id and others with `int`.

Comment: The results will not match : 1 != "1"

Comment: Widgets.OwnerId  is associated with Owner.Id so the types are same.

Comment: string comparison rules are different between DBMS and EF's prepared queries. try changing the PK of owners to long if you want reliable comparisons

Comment: The owner.Id Fields are Microsoft scaffold guids.  when I change them to all be the same it has no affect on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> > Widgets.OwnerId is associated with Owner.Id so the types are same

But the sort order and equality aren't necessarily the same between .NET and the database.  So you could have a collation conflict between the database and EF, where the Widget.OwnerId's match Owner.Id's in the collation of the database, but not in .NET's string comparison rules.

EG

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ef62test
{
    class Program
    {

        public partial class Owner
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string OwnerName { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Widget> Widgets { get; } = new HashSet<Widget>();

        }

        public partial class Widget
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string OwnerId { get; set; }
            public string WidgetName { get; set; }
            public string WidgetType { get; set; }
            public virtual Owner Owners { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Model1 : DbContext
        {

            public virtual DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.Widgets)
                    .WithRequired(e => e.Owners)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.OwnerId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Model1>());

            string ownerId = "owner1";
            using (var db = new Model1())
            {
                db.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
                var o = new Owner() { Id = ownerId };

                db.Owners.Add(o);

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    o.Widgets.Add(new Widget());
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                ownerId = o.Id;

                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update widgets set ownerId = UPPER(ownerId);");
            }

            using (var db = new Model1())
            {
                db.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                var owner = db.Owners.Include(o => o.Widgets).Where(o => o.Id == ownerId).First();

                Console.WriteLine(owner.Widgets.Count());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried changing id to String... it has no affect on the query.

Comment: The collation conflict is just a guess.  You'll need to create a simple, self-contained repro to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Appreciate the assistance. This is a very simplified version.  Just been banging my head on the desk trying to see why the include is ignored.  Seems like it should be working.

Comment: Would it make any difference if the Owners table is Technically AspNetUsers table that is AutoGenerated by the framework?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the aspnetusers table, does it exist in the same context as your other table? That would explain why EF was struggling even if the database is not?

Comment: True, Doubled Checked and they are using the same DbContext,  I even moved them into the same file incase that had something to do with it and Still no luck. :(